# How to have a nine patch image only expand horizontally?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a nine patch image that I would like to center vertically in a view and only have it expand horizontally.

I have tried putting two expandable regions on the nine patch (one above, one below) but depending on the density of the screen, if the view ends up being an even number of pixels tall and the nine patch is odd tall, then the image breaks slightly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A valid nine patch image must have at least one expandable region at the top and one on the left, regions you draw on the right and below are for specifying paddings, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

If you want your nine patch image only to expand horizontally, you will have to prepare your original image with the height you want and the width as narrow as one pixel, and draw a dot at the top and another one on the left, note the expandable region we specify on the left is just for making it a valid nine patch. Now you can put the image inside a layout(set the height for the layout as that of your image), set `android:layout_graviy="center_vertical"` for the image, you then have the image expanded horizontally.

Comment: A single dot on the center might be a better option depending on your image.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't think it is possible. For a nine patch image, you can only put dots around the edges of the image.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , I in-fact was talking about the center of the left edge :)

Comment: Without a dot on the top, it is not a valid nine patch, eclipse doesn't like it and you will get a compile time error. `No marked region found along edge. - Found along top edge.`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand horizontally without spoiling the left and right side design. 
<strike>What I did was to add additional 1px (transparent) at both the top and the bottom of the image.
After that, on the left side, I added the black dot on the row where I had added the extra padding. As well as the expandable area at the top of the image.
I did this for all the 4 different density and it works will well :)</strike>

With the help of [radley's scale and fill](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/), I just draw black line on the left side.

To make it center vertically as mention in your post, just add in `android:layout_graviy="center_vertical"` for linear layout or `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for relative layout.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want your image to expand in vertically, then why cant you go directly with out using 9-patch by keeping other one as fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following example [Example Link](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-nine-patch-image-example/),
You can set the expandable area and have a horizonatal expanding nine patch